# FAB (floating action button) doesn't float

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-support-library, android-custom-view

I've tried to use the floatingactionbutton element but it doesn't float in UI layout, the floating button occupies part of the layout and isn't over the component, in my case is a viewpager,

[button doesn't float](https://i.stack.imgur.com/944ou.png)

this is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.frases.frases.FraseMain"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's because you are using LinearLayout as the root layout. You need FrameLayout to stack elements over one another, and FAB needs to be the last child node because it needs to stay on top of every other views.

```
<FrameLayout>
  <LinearLayout>
    ...
  </LinearLayout>

  <!-- FAB be the last node inside FrameLayout here -->
  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem with your contribution and the contribution of Riten

Comment: I'm glad i could help :-)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if soft keyboard is shown.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you have to use coordinator layout, you can simply use floating button with below code as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/dashboard_bg"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<!-- here you can have your viewpager -->

 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/dashboardShowActionsFab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="4dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, It works well, I solved the problem with your contribution.

Comment: Wow..happy to help you guys...If it helped you ..please do accept the answer.. :D

Answer (score 1):

use CoordinatorLayout like below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

         <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

          <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
              android:layout_margin="16dp"
              android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
              app:layout_anchor="@id/lvToDoList"
              app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```