# Button OnClick in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, button, tabs, onclick

:) I started doing an app with Tabs and fragments, but in the fragments' classes when adding OnClick to buttons nothing happens when the button is pressed

There's `fragment_sub_page02.xml` :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="layout.SubPage02">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"

    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    />
```

and that's `SubPage02.java`:

```
public class SubPage02 extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
Button mbutton;

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public SubPage02() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment SubPage02.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static SubPage02 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    SubPage02 fragment = new SubPage02();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }

    LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_page02,
            container, false);

    // note that we're looking for a button with id="@+id/myButton" in your inflated layout
    // Naturally, this can be any View; it doesn't have to be a button
    Button mButton = (Button) mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.button);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // here you set what you want to do when user clicks your button,
            // e.g. launch a new activity
        }
    });

    // after you've done all your manipulation, return your layout to be shown
    return mLinearLayout;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

After inputting several things in the onclick and nothing happened...
Where should i put the button's function ...?

Thanks to everyone! :)

EDIT 1 (`MainActivity.java`):

```
import java.util.zip.Inflater;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
public FloatingActionButton fab;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);


    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            animateFab(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });


}
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";


    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 2) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
            return rootView;
        } else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_page02, container, false);
            return rootView;
        } else {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "AlertDialog";
            case 1:
                return "Toast";
            case 2:
                return "Snackbar";
        }
        return null;

    }


}
```

Comment: what you want to do on button click? , and you are doing the right way by implementing `onClick` method.

Comment: `After inputting several things in the onclick and nothing happened` what have you tried?

Comment: I put `Toast.makeText(getView().getApplicationContext, R.string.ToastText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`
`startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS), 0);`
`Snackbar snackbar1 = Snackbar.make(getView().getApplicationContext, R.string.SnackBarText, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
snackbar1.show();`

Comment: that  if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }
code looks weird, 

could you try it without it? see if it works? also you could try altering the background of the button (add a color) to see if it really is there, because if the above condition fires, and the view returned is null it won't even show the button

Comment: `Button mButton = (Button) mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), R.string.ToastText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        return mLinearLayout;` 
initially there was no `if (container ==null)` but with or without it and adding a background color didn't help :/

Comment: Implemented OnClickListener a few times , every time asking for abstract class

Comment: The Fragment looks ok. Please share the code for adding it to the Activity

Comment: Updated the question with the Activity's code :) ( I cut some stuff like fab, systembartint and menu_main, so if there are addtitional elements, that's why )
The fragment I am editing is fragment_sub_page02.xml :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `TabLayout` requires a new instance of `PlaceholderFragment` each time a new page is selected, so let's take a closer look at its `onCreateView()`:

Depending on the value of `getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)`, a specific layout is inflated. If the value is 1, the layout will be the same as for `SubPage02`.

But this does not mean that an instance of `SubPage02` will be created, they just happen to share the same layout file.

So the `OnClickListener` has to be set in the `onCreateView()` of `PlaceholderFragment`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 2) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
        return rootView;
    } else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_page02, container, false);

        Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // here you set what you want to do when user clicks your button,

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    } else {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much ! :) Solved a problem taking a week of nerve-wrecking trial and errors ... :) Cheers

Comment: But just something to ask, what is the fragment's java for then ? 
When i deleted the Fragment's class nothing changed ... Is it necessary to have it though?

Comment: @ValentinFilyov - you don't need it for your architecture. I think some people might want to return different Fragments from `PlaceholderFragment#newInstance()`, e.g. an instance of `SubPage02` for the value 1. If you do it this way, `onCreateView()` of PlaceholderFragment would still be called though, so you would have to determine to which class you should cast and then write something like this: `((SubPage02)this).onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)`. Then the child class method would be called... but I must say, I`m not really sure this approach is a good idea.

Comment: The important thing about `onCreateView()`: it will only be called if an instance of this Fragment class will be attached to the UI. So if you just call `newInstance()`, it won`t be executed. It is executed in this case, because the TabLayout handles the rest.

Comment: What do I do if the fab moves with the layout ? :/

Comment: @ValentinFilyov - I'm sorry but so far I haven't worked with FAB. Maybe it requires a certain type of parent layout, similar to NavigationView, to really "float"? [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194370/fab-floating-action-button-doesnt-float) may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The id you were looking is `myButton` and you wrote `button`. Also, XML layout `fragment_sub_page02`. For inflater try the `getLayoutInflater()`.

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_page02,
        container, false);

// note that we're looking for a button with id="@+id/myButton" in your inflated layout
// Naturally, this can be any View; it doesn't have to be a button
Button mButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.myButton);
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // here you set what you want to do when user clicks your button,
        // e.g. launch a new activity
    }
});

// after you've done all your manipulation, return your layout to be shown
return view;
```

Let me know if helped.

Comment: My button's id is `button` 
and it asks for Bundle in the `getLayoutInflater`'s brackets :D